# Finding lat/lng and users with radius ios

Tags: ios, geolocation

I am having trouble finding what I need to do the following. I need for the user to be able to put in a city, state, country and get the latitude and longitude which I will then store in my database. Also later in my app I want to search for users within a certain radius.

I am not asking for code atm, but what iOS sdk(s) are there available to do this? I thought for sure google would have something but searching for "GEO radius iOS" does not provide much help. Surely there is some service available with an SDK to do this.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/clgeocoder ?

Comment: @Paulw11 Thanks for that. I see the requests are limited. I do not think this is what I need. My app is a social app where users can search for other users within a radius of themselves. In the web version I am using google maps to have an autocomplete textfield when they type and address. I was looking into google maps iOS api, but am not sure it offers the functionality.

Comment: I think this may work to get the latitude and lognitude of an address. The places api. I already have my server back-end able to search via long/lat - radius. I just need a way in the iOS app to search via a city, state where i can grab the lat/lng and pass onto my backend.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/places/ios-sdk/autocomplete